# Rotas - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes

Estou utilizando rotas do `angularjs 1.6` e estou com problemas na parte de filtro de conexão com java.

Quando eu faço o login no meu sistema e acesso uma página do meu sistema, o filtro funciona normalmente, mas quando eu abro outra página sem atualizar a página, o filtro é ignorado.

Creio que seja por causa da url que as rotas do angularjs estão montando ou algo do gênero.

**Dando um exemplo mais explicativo:**

Faço o login no sistema e acesso `/users` na URL, o filtro funciona corretamente. Sem fazer o refresh na tela, eu acesso `/appointments` e o filtro é ignorado, não cai no debug da classe de filtro.

Configurei as rotas dessa maneira:

```
/* Configuração de rotas */
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
    })

    $routeProvider.when('/appointments', {
        templateUrl : 'views/appointment/appointment.html',
        controller : 'AppointmentController'
    })

    $routeProvider.when('/patients', {
        templateUrl : 'views/patient/patient.html',
        controller : 'PatientController'
    })

    $routeProvider.when('/users', {
        templateUrl : 'views/user/user.html',
        controller : 'UserController'
    })

    $routeProvider.when('/services', {
        templateUrl : 'views/service/service.html',
        controller : 'ServiceController'
    })
});
```

Comment: O filtro é ignorado no sentido que ele não vai pro `appointments` ou ele vai sem mostrar o `login`?

Comment: No sentido de não respeitar o filtro... Eu preciso que o filtro seja aplicado em todos os acessos das páginas. Preciso que seja realizado o filtro de conexão, quando o usuário tentar acessar /appointments, entendeu?

Comment: Pensa no seguinte cenário... o usuário logou no sistema, acessou /users e ficou um tempo sem interação com o sistema e a sessão expirou. Quando ele for acessar /appointments, a sessão não estará ativa e ele deve ser redirecionado para a página de login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que você possa criar áreas de acesso restritas com *AngularJS* você pode optar por utilizar cookies.
Utilize a propriedade `sessionStorage` para armazenar o id de sessão do usuário ou outro dado que identifica a sessão do mesmo.
Exemplo:

```
/* Aqui é gravado a sessão do usuário, neste exemplo vamos utilizar o
email como a sessão dele (Não vamos utilizar criptografia para não complicar o exemplo)*/

function setSession(email){
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
}

/* Recupera o dado armazenado */
function getSession(){
    return sessionStorage.getItem("email");
}

/* Verifica se a sessão existe, caso não exista, redireciona para a pagina principal */
function verificaSessao($location){
    if(getSession() == null){
        $location.path('/');
    }
}

app.controller('AppointmentController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 
    function($scope, $http, $location){
    verificaSessao($location);
}]);
```